# The requested resource is not available 2

Tags: java, servlets

I've the problem with my first servlet.
I've created index.jsp, classes and servlet. The codes is as follows:

**Index.jsp**:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8"
pageEncoding="utf-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Blog</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
      <thead>
           <tr>
                <td>Username:</td>
                <td>Title:</td>
                <td>Message:</td>
           </tr>
      </thead>
      <c:forEach items="${messages}" var="mess">
           <tr>
                <td>${mess.name}</td>
                <td>${mess.title}</td>
                <td>${mess.text}</td>
           </tr>
      </c:forEach>
 </table>

</body>
</html>
```

**BlogServlet.java**:

```
package servlets;


import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import blog.Message;



/**
 * Servlet implementation class for Servlet: BlogServlet
 *
*/
 public class BlogServlet extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet implements     javax.servlet.Servlet {
 static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 private EntityManagerFactory factory;
 private EntityManager em;
 /* (non-Java-doc)
 * @see javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public BlogServlet() {
    super();
    factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("blog");
    em = factory.createEntityManager();
}       

/* (non-Java-doc)
 * @see javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    List<Message> messages = 
           em.createQuery("select * from Messages m").getResultList();
   request.setAttribute("messages", messages);
   request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
}   

/* (non-Java-doc)
 * @see javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.doGet(request, response);
}               
}
```

**web.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>BlogServlet</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
  <description></description>
  <display-name>BlogServlet</display-name>
  <servlet-name>BlogServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>servlets.BlogServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>BlogServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/servlets/BlogServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

---

The Tomcat returns the error message "The requested resource is not available".
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which resource is tomcat saying not available? Can you post the entire error message?

Comment: Also, are you seeing a stack trace in your console?

Comment: @irina What is the URL you are trying to access? And please post the entire stack trace, else it would be difficult to track the bug.

Comment: @irina Why are you calling `doGet` from `doPost`?

Comment: i have the same problem! Do you have any solution?!! Only difference is that I use redirect rather than forward.